# How to take derivative of the argument of an interpolating function

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, complex, interpolation

I am trying to plot the derivative of the argument of an interpolating function `u[t, x]` with respect to $x$. Here, `u[t, x]` is the solution of Non-linear Schrodinger equation. It seems that there is a problem while taking the derivative of `Arg[u[t, x]]`. In fact, the derivative of `Arg[u[t, x]]` calculated for arbitrary $x,t$ gives a complex number, but it is supposed to be real.

Can anyone please help?

Here is the code I was trying.

```
sol = NDSolve[
       Evaluate[{I D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x, x] + 
         1/2 Abs[u[t, x]]^2 u[t, x] == 0, u[0, x] == 2 Sech[2 x]}], 
       u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]

g[t_, x_] = Evaluate[Arg[u[t, x]] /. sol]
h[t_, x_] = D[g[t, x], x]

DensityPlot[h[t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

For example, `h[2, 4]` returns `{0.28502 + 0.459296 I}`.

Comment: Did you find the solution of Equation? I think  you need one more boundary condition (i.e. u[t,x=L])

Comment: Yes, it works without the periodic boundary condition.

Comment: Please notice though `NDSolve` *seems* to work without the b.c., the solution it found is probably not the desired one. Check this post for more details: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871 If you're trying to solve your equation in $-\infty<x<\infty$, you need artificial b.c., check e.g. this post for more details: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145478/1871

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: As pointed out by @GopalVerma in their answer, I think the problem is with what Mathematica returns when asked for `Arg'[x + I y]`.  Related:  [Issue when simplifying an expression containing Arg.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149752/issue-when-simplifying-an-expression-containing-arg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here seems to be that Mathematica is giving strange results when you ask it to take the derivative of the function `Arg`.  As an example of this, suppose you take $\arg(e^{ix})$, where $x$ is a real number.  You would expect that $\arg(e^{ix}) = x \; (\mathrm{mod} \; 2\pi)$, and therefore the derivative of this function should be a constant for most values of $x$.  But this isn't what Mathematica does:

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[D[Arg[Exp[I x]], x]]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

You *do* get the expected results if you insert a `ComplexExpand`, and if your expression is something that simplifies when you use `ComplexExpand`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[D[ComplexExpand[Arg[Exp[I x]]], x]]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

However, `ComplexExpand` can't do much with an arbitrary `InterpolatingFunction`, so this method isn't suitable here.  There may be some well-justified complex analysis reason why the first snippet above returns the given plot (it appears that the result is $i e^{2ix}$), but I'm not sure what it is just now.  Alternately, it may be a bug.

To work around this, you can rewrite your equations so that they solve for the real and imaginary parts of $u$ separately, and then use the usual sorts of formulas to find the phase of $u$ and its derivatives:

```
eqns = {I D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x, x] + 
 1/2 Abs[u[t, x]]^2 u[t, x] == 0, u[0, x] == 2 Sech[2 x]};
expandedeqns = Flatten[ComplexExpand[
    ReIm[eqns /. {u[x_, t_] -> uR[x, t] + I uI[x, t], 
      Derivative[y__][u][x_, t_] -> 
       Derivative[y][uR][x, t] + I Derivative[y][uI][x, t]}]]]
sol = NDSolve[Evaluate[expandedeqns], {uR, uI}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]

g[t_, x_] = ArcTan[uR[t, x], uI[t, x]] /. First[sol]
h[t_, x_] = D[g[t, x], x]
DensityPlot[h[t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Finally, as noted by xzczd in the comments, you should not expect this answer to be correct unless you have fully specified the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Comment: @Michael Seifert  Hi, this code cannot run successfully in v13.0.

Answer (score 3):

```
D[Arg[x + y*I], x]
(*Derivative[1][Arg][x + I y]*)

D[ComplexExpand[Arg[x + y*I], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], x]
(*-(y/(x^2 + y^2))*)
```

But in case it is coming zero

```
D[ComplexExpand[Arg[u[t, x]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], x]
(*0*)
```

Comment: I'm trying to find out the derivative of Arg[u], not Abs[D[u]]. They are not same.

Comment: Arg is also working. You can see the updated figure.

Comment: Not Arg[D[u[x,t]]], I want to calculate D[Arg[u[x,t]]]. They are not same!

Comment: you can try with D[ComplexExpand[Arg[u[t, x]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], x]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is, extract the data from `InterpolatingFunction`, modify it and build a new interpolating function:

```
solfunc = u /. sol[[1]];

solfuncarg = ListInterpolation[solfunc["ValuesOnGrid"] // Arg, solfunc["Coordinates"]]

h2 = Derivative[0, 1][solfuncarg]
```

The structure of `InterpolatingFunction` is discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/1871).

Finally I'd like to emphasize once again that the missing of boundary condition (b.c.) is a serious problem and you really need to add proper b.c. to obtain the desired answer.

Comment: Thank you. I saw the post related to boundary condition, so now I have imposed a periodic boundary condition.

Comment: @sudipta Glad it helps. If you think our answers have resolved your problem, you may [click on the check mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/284701) to accept one.